# Duplicate logging events generated for VPC in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-vpc

I have a cloud function that pushes notifications to slack channel whenever there is any change to VPC (creating a new VPC, addition / deletions of subnets, change to route tables) or any update to IAM & Bucket policies in the GCP project.

**CF Functionality**

For any new event in the GCP project, log sink (with inclusion filters) would publish message to a pub sub topic. The subscription pushes the message to cloud function and triggers it.

When I add / modify / remove a VPC, subnet or a firewall rule. The cloud function triggers twice pushing two notifications to the slack channel in an interval of 12 seconds. These are identical message for the same event. See below.

[image]

However when I make any changes to IAM policy only one event is generated so only one notification to the slack channel. See below.

[image]

I am unable to figure out why GCP logging is generating identical events for same VPC action triggering two notifications in the slack channel. If this is feature how can I remove the duplicacies of events.

**Note: I pass method names to the inclusion filter to query for events.**

Comment: Without details on the actual events, my guess is the first is the "START" event and the second is the "COMPLETION" event. Expand the events and review the event details.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the config and show full entries?